# bluemix cf reports "No orgs found"

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashboard

I can see and operate organization in dashboard. But cannot find any org in cf command line.

```
C:\Users\zlf>cf login -u 3218789763@qq.com -o suisl -s dev
API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net

Password>
Authenticating...
OK

FAILED
Error finding org suisl
Organization suisl not found


API endpoint:   https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.40.0)
User:           3218789763@qq.com
No org or space targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG -s SPACE'

C:\Users\zlf>cf orgs
Getting orgs as 3218789763@qq.com...

name
No orgs found
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdZJ4.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using **US South Region**:

use these commands:

```
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

If you are using **United Kingdom region**:

use these commands:

```
cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

**for Sydney region**

```
cf api https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

**for Germany region**

```
cf api https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

you can know which region, org and space is currently set typing:

```
cf target
```

If you are using the 'bluemix' plugin you can use the below command

example: 
`bx api <apiLink>` and `bx target`

Answer (score 2):

you have created the org in the Sydney Region but you are looking for the Org in the US region (https://api.ng.bluemix.net).
For Sydney please use the following API endpoint: api.au-syd.bluemix.net

To find the CF API endpoints for each region please refer to the [docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/overview/index.html#ov_arch).

Comment: i was search for this answer for so long!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change the region to your region and then target the org and space. You may target your region using below command:

ibmcloud target --cf-api 'https://api.REGION.cf.cloud.ibm.com' -r REGION -o

Change REGION with your region(eu-gb) for London use your ibm cloud email id for org.

Thanks,

This message was taken from Anamika Agawarl from Coursera.